# the Like box iframe that facebook generate for me is not working

Tags: facebook

Hi the  Like Box iFrame Generated Code not working, It make the space for the like box on the sidebar but doesn't shows information. The code is:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?
  href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fmicky.aleon&amp;
  width=250&amp;height=290&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;
  show_faces=true&amp;header=true&amp;stream=false&amp;
  show_border=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
  style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:250px; height:290px;"
  allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I tried following previous answers in this site but it is not working for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just add a

> https:

before the //, so it should look like:

```
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?
    href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fmicky.aleon&amp;
    width=250&amp;height=290&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;
    show_faces=true&amp;header=true&amp;stream=false&amp;
    show_border=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
    style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:250px; height:290px;"
    allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: It is for some people, don't just down vote me if you have no clue.